# Move an object based on where your cursor is

Tags: python, python-turtle

I made a basic pong by going through a tutorial and tweaking a few things, currently I'd like the left paddle which is the variable `paddle_a` to be moved based on where the cursor is while still maintaining its x value. Or, in other words, moving up and down based on the y value of the mouse. I've looked around the internet and couldn't find anything that would help me in this case so help would be appreciated.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Pong")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=0.5)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-380, 0)


# Ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("square")
ball.color("white")
ball.shapesize(stretch_len=0.75, stretch_wid=0.75)
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.dx = 0.3
ball.dy = 0.3



# Functions
def paddle_a_up():
  y = paddle_a.ycor()
  y += 10
  paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_a_down():
  y = paddle_a.ycor()
  y -= 10
  paddle_a.sety(y)


# Keybinding
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "w")
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, "s")

# Main game loop
while True:
 wn.update()

 # Move the ball
 ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
 ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

 # Border checking
 if ball.ycor() > 290:
   ball.sety(290)
   ball.dy *= -1

 if ball.ycor() < -290:
   ball.sety(-290)
   ball.dy *= -1

 if ball.xcor() > 390:
   ball.goto(0, 0)
   ball.dx *= -1

 if ball.xcor() < -390:
   ball.goto(0, 0)
   ball.dx *= -1
```

Comment: You could consider using pygame which handles mouse events quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach using the mouse `ondrag()` event on the paddle instead of key events.  Click and hold on the paddle while you move it up and down.  The ball will continue to move independently:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# Functions
def paddle_move(x, y):
    paddle_a.sety(y)

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Pong")
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)

# Paddle A
paddle_a = Turtle()
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=0.5)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.setx(-380)

# Ball
ball = Turtle()
ball.shape("square")
ball.color("white")
ball.shapesize(stretch_len=0.75, stretch_wid=0.75)
ball.penup()

ball.dx = 1.3  # user defined properties
ball.dy = 1.3

# Keybinding
paddle_a.ondrag(paddle_move)

# Main game loop
def play():
    # Move the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # Border checking
    if ball.ycor() > 290:
        ball.sety(290)
        ball.dy *= -1
    elif ball.ycor() < -290:
        ball.sety(-290)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if not -390 <= ball.xcor() <= 390:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(play)

play()

screen.mainloop()
```